# Getting number instead of text for android notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have implemented android notification in my application and it is working fine except that it shows a number instead of the actual message body. Here is teh screen shot of what I am getting,

[image]

This is the code I have,

```
public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;
    private int MESSAGE_TYPE ;


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        String type = data.getString("type");
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Load Messages"))
        {
            MESSAGE_TYPE = Global.NOTIFICATION_LOAD_MESSAGE;
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new HandyManEvents.ReloadMessages(true));
        }
        else
        {
            MESSAGE_TYPE = Global.NOTIFICATION_LOAD_LIVE_JOBS;
        }
        createNotification(from, message);
    }

    // Creates notification based on title and body received
    private void createNotification(String title, String body) {

        Context context = getBaseContext();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("menuFragment", MESSAGE_TYPE);
        PendingIntent pending= PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(pending)
                .setContentText(body);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

Any clue whats going wrong here?

**Updated**
When app is running in foreground I am seeing this behaviour. This is the bundle I got from notification,

```
Bundle[{type=Load Messages, notification=Bundle[{e=1, body=You have a new message, icon=app_icon, title=New Message}], collapse_key=com.company.app}]
```

How to extract the title and body from Bundle?

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, `data.getString("message")` is that value. Where is `Bundle data` coming from?

Comment: Bundle data is coming from server. This happens mainly if I recieve notifications with app open.

Answer (score 0):

You are uing google play services APIs to capture GCM messages. The class in which this code belongs is the one that extends [GcmListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService.html#inherited-constant-summary) and you're overriding `onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data)` which takes the sender ID as the first argument (from) and that what appears in your notification as you assigning it as a title.

You need to parse the bundle in a correct way to be able to get the data and that depends on the payload the server sends. You can see which key is available in the bundle by logging it

```
for (String key : bundle.keySet()){
    Log.d(TAG, key + " = " + bundle.get(key));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are correct but that happens only when I have the app in foreground. If its in background i am getting proper notifications. Please see the updated question.

Comment: You shouldn't modify the question to present another one.